# React & Redux - Part of state gets updated when it shouldn't?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm new to React-Redux-Typescript combination so I need some help and a sanity check from you guys and gals. I'm not in the office ATM so code provided is written on the fly, from memory, and it's probably not syntactically correct but please check if the general idea/ approach is correct. I'll update with proper code as soon as I'm back in the office. Until then, please assume I have defined proper interfaces, types and imported and exported everything.

Consider state example below. Problem I have is when I want to update `sections.firstSection.title`, `initial.firstSection.title` also gets updated with same value when it shouldn't as it's not defined anywhere. Why is that happening? My idea is to preserve initial state so I can reference it when I need to reset value in an input field, for example. But as it gets updated, I end up with two duplicate branches.

State example:

```
const initialState = {
    sections: {
        firstSection: {
            visible: true,
            enabled: true,
            changed: false,
            title: "Step one"
        },
        secondSection: {
            visible: true,
            enabled: true,
            changed: false,
            title: "Step two"
        }
    },
    initial: {
        firstSection: {
            visible: true,
            enabled: true,
            changed: false,
            title: "Step one"
        },
        secondSection: {
            visible: true,
            enabled: true,
            changed: false,
            title: "Step two"
        }
    }
}

const firstSectionData = {
    visible: true,
    enabled: false,
    changed: false,
    title: "First section"
}

initialState.sections.firstSection = firstSectionData;
```

Initialization:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById(containerID) as HTMLElement
)
```

Reducers:

```
export function rootReducer(state: StoreState, action: Actions): StoreState {    
        let newState = {...state};
        switch(action.type){
            case action.UPDATE_FIRST:
                newState.sections.firstSection = updateSection(newState.sections.firstSection, action);
                break;
            case action.UPDATE_SECOND:
                newState.sections.firstSection = updateSection(newState.sections.secondSection, action);
               break;
            case action.RESET_FIRST:
                newState.sections.firstSection = resetSection(newState.sections.firstSection, action);
                break;
            case action.RESET_SECOND:
                newState.sections.secondSection = resetSection(newState.sections.firstSection, action);
               break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return newState;
    }

    function updateSection(state: StoreState.Sections, action: Actions): StoreState.Sections {
        let newState = {...state};
        switch(action.type){
            case action.UPDATE_FIRST:
                newState.firstSection.title = action.value;
                break;
            case action.UPDATE_SECOND:
                newState.secondSection.title = action.value;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return newState;
    }

    function resetSection(state: StoreState, action: Actions): StoreState {
        let newState = {...state};
        switch(action.type){
            case action.RESET_FIRST:
                newState.sections.firstSection.title = newState.initial.firstSection.title;
                break;
            case action.RESET_SECOND:
                newState.sections.secondSection.title = newState.initial.secondSection.title;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return newState;
    }
```

Actions:

```
function updateSection(type: string, value: string): StateUpdate {
    if(type == "first"){
            return {
                type: UPDATE_FIRST,
                value: value
            }
    } else if( type == "second" ) {
            return {
                type: UPDATE_SECOND,
                value: value
            }
   }
}

function resetSection(type: string, value: string): StateReset {
    if(type == "first"){
            return {
                type: RESET_FIRST,
                value: value
            }
    } else if( type == "second" ) {
            return {
                type: RESET_SECOND,
                value: value
            }
   }
}
```

Dispatch:

```
function mapStateToProps(state: StoreState){
    return {
        firstSection: state.sections.firstSection,
        secondSection: state.sections.secondSection
    }
};

function mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>){
    return {
        updateSection: (value: string) => {
            dispatch(updateSection(value))
        },
        resetSection: (value: string) => {
            dispatch(resetSection(value))
        }
    }
  };

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

App component

```
interface Props {
    firstSection: StoreState.Sections,
    secondSection: StoreState.Sections,
    updateSection: (value: string) => void,
    resetSection: (value: string) => void,
}

const App = (allProps: Props, action: Actions) => {
    const {firstSection, secondSection, updateSection, resetSection} = allProps;

    function expressUpdate(value?: string){
        updateSection("first", value);
    }

    function expressReset(value?: string){
        resetSection("second", value);
    }

    return(
        <div>
        <section>
            <ButtonField clickAction={expressReset} />
            <TextField text={firstSection.title} changeEvent={expressUpdate} />
        </section>
        <section>
            <ButtonField clickAction={expressReset} />
            <TextField text={secondSection.title} changeEvent={expressUpdate} />
        </section>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Input text field component

```
interface Props {
    text: string;
    changeEvent: (value: string) => void;
}

function TextField(allProps: Props){
    const {text, changeEvent, ...props} = allProps;
    return(
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e)=>changeEvent(e.currentTarget.value)} />
    )
}
```

I understand that's a lot of stuff to digest but I hope someone will be able to warn me of whatever mistake I might be making.
Thanks in advance.

Update: Okay, now I've edited code to reflect what I'm really using.

Answer (score 0):

Switch cases fall through!

You have this problem throughout all of the code above.  Switch statements are *not* fancy `if/else` statements.  They work differently.

When entering a switch statement, you will jump to the case that matches your input.  You will then *continue through the switch case* until you hit a `break;` command, which will exit you from the switch case.

For instance;

```
testSwitch = (x) => {

    switch(x) {
        case(1):
            console.log('one');
        case(2):
            console.log('two');
            break;
        case(3):
            console.log('three');
    }
}

testSwitch(1); // logs: 'one \n two'
testSwitch(2); // logs: 'two'
testSwitch(3); // logs: 'three'
```

Your lack of `break;` statements is causing much of your code to behave like `testSwitch(1)`.

Comment: I'm also seeing some distinct issues with mutating nested state, as well.

Comment: Oh. I removed break statements intentionally as I got warning that part of code is unreachable and VS Code couldn't build the package. I didn't pay much thought as it made some sense return statements would exit switch case. I'll try with if/else and then update code above if necessary.

Comment: @markerikson: Can you provide an example or point at problematic code?

Comment: Return statements WILL exit the switch statements (since they cease execution of the function).  But most of your switches don't have returns or breaks.  `rootReducer`, `updateSection`, and `resetSection` in particular.

Comment: @gravityplanx: My bad. Breaks exist in functions you mention but I forgot to write them above. They didn't exist in Actions though. I updated code above.

Comment: Example: `let newState = {...state]; newState.firstSection.title = action.value;` will mutate `firstSection`, because you only copied the first level of nesting.  See the [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) section in the Redux docs, specifically "Common Mistake #2" about not copying all levels of nesting that need to be updated.

Comment: @markerikson: Correct. Turns up like the problem was with the way I updated state in reducers: `initialState.sections.firstSection = firstSectionData;`

Instead of doing the spread thing: `initialState.sections.firstSection = {... firstSectionData};`
Thanks. :)